# Which shell I'm using?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zsh

I try to learn bioinformatic and I'm using MacMonterey 12.6 so I need to using bash. I arrange from "System Preferences > User & Groups > Advanced Option". As you can see in screenshot, something is wrong but I couldn't find it. Please help me!

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with `bash` (which you aren't using) or `zsh` (which you are).

Answer (score 1):

Mac does not have `apt-get` - it's for Linux. Use [brew](https://brew.sh/)

---

Try using [homebrew-stew](https://github.com/crockpotveggies/homebrew-stew):

```bash
brew install brew install homebrew/science/tabix
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to change to bash, you can simply do below

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Did you install apt-get thru homebrew? It does not come with Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ZSH. The `$SHELL` variable represents the user *preferred* shell, not current.